# Ponteiro para método

Tags: c++, método

Comecei a estudar orientação a objetos e estou tentando chamar ponteiro para método, porém estou com dificuldades.

A implementação do método `startAllegro` da classe `Application` é o seguinte:

```
void Application::startAllegro(){
    allegro_init();
    install_timer();
    install_keyboard();
    set_color_depth(32);
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, width, heigth, 0, 0);
    set_window_title(&name[0]);
    set_close_button_callback(quitSwap);
}
```

O outro método que estou tentando passar como ponteiro é o `quitSwap`, na rotina `set_close_button_callback`.

`set_close_button_callback` é uma rotina da allegro e tem o seguinte protótipo: `set_close_button_callback(void (*proc)(void));`

A implementação que fiz do método quitSwap é:

```
void Application::quitSwap(){
    quit = true;
}
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro no método `startAllegro`:

`application.cpp:20: error: argument of type 'void (Application::)()' does not match 'void (*)()'`

Já tentei de tudo para resolver, mas não consegui. Alguém mais experiente em POO poderia me ajudar? Obrigado

Comment: Hum... Talvez um *casting* da função resolva. Tenta fazer a chamada assim: `set_close_button_callback((void (*)(void)) quitSwap);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tenho experiência com Allegro, mas o que você está tentando fazer não vai funcionar porque você está passando um ponteiro para função membro quando o esperado é um ponteiro para função livre.

A função está esperando algo do tipo `void (*)()`, então você poderia ter algo assim:

```
void quit_handler() { ... }

//...

set_close_button_callback(quit_handler);
```

Mas você está tentando passar uma função membro. A mensagem de erro já está dando a dica: a função que vocẽ está passando é do tipo `void (Application::*)()`. C++ diferencia ponteiros de função livre e ponteiros de função membro porque estas tem o parâmetro oculto `this`.

```
void Application::quitSwap(){
    quit = true;
}
```

é mais ou menos equivalente a:

```
void Application_quitSwap(Application *this){
    this->quit = true;
}
```

Por isso não está funcionando. A função que você está chamando espera uma função sem parâmetros, mas você está passando uma com um parâmetro.